# How to force HTML5 appCache to never fail (online, offline, or remote server down)

Tags: android, html5-appcache

I have an Android web app using a manifest file caching remote resources (html, images, css, js) that work fine for moments but I can't find a way to make it work all the time... A lot of things seems to make the app load fail randomly (not always):

- Restarting device
- Stopping WIFI
- Starting WIFI
- Remote server down
- Just waiting some time

Any idea how to make an appCache app running in any situation? Is appCache a mature and stable feature?

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Comment: What do you mean that it fails *some times*? What fails? Loading the static assets (CSS, JS, images) doesn't work? What do you have in your appcache file?

Comment: I receive the message: Application Error Cannot connect to server (http://.....) when starting the app on my phone. Normally, the app should load from cache when server is not accessible. It may work well during one day and next day it stop working...